# disable flash audio in object params?

Tags: flash, audio, param

Is there a way of disabling the audio in a flash file via the object params?

Comment: this may not be possible. My only other option may be to create a container movie which mutes the sounds. This is not the most elegant solution but I may be forced to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no abstract way of disabling sound via the embed params (i.e. it's only possible if the content knows how to disable its own sounds based on something you pass in).

But using a parent container that kills sound (or more properly sets the volume to 0) and loads in content should be a viable workaround. Just keep in mind that there are some edge cases where content made in certain ways might not work correctly if it's loaded into another SWF.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details?

Are you trying to access a swf via flashvars? the object params are just variables, you would need to access a method to be able to mute the sound. If you have access to the script this is pretty straighforward if not the container seems to be the solution, in the container , you could create an instance of the SoundMixer which controls the global sound in Flash and call the stopAll() method.